# How does one make an applet scroll?

Tags: java, swing, applet, scroll, jscrollpane

I have been trying to use JScrollPane with my applet, but it doesn't work. I have a JPanel to which I add 20 buttons, and I want to be able to scroll up and down this JPanel. Instead, the scrollbars do not appear. When I use setPreferredSize they still did not appear even though only about 3 of the buttons are being displayed and the rest are cut off. If I do not use setPreferredSize, there might as well not be any scrollbars because I have to make the window big enough to see all of the buttons. If I try to make the scrollbars always visible, they appear but do nothing. I tried the exact same code with JFrame instead of Applet, and it works fine, but I need it to be an applet. Is JScrollPane incompatible with applets? (Note: I tried to use an outer JPanel and add the scrollable panel to it, but it changed nothing). Changing the layouts also doesn't fix the problem. I have attached a simplified version of my code, but it displays the same errors.

Here is the code I have:

```
JPanel scrollPanel = new JPanel();
scrollPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(scrollPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) scrollPanel.add(new JButton("Button " + i));
add(scrollPanel);
validate();
```

Comment: some code would be of help..JScrollPane is what you need to use. So basically you just add the anel you want to have the scroll functionality to the scrollpane and add the scrollpane to the main container..Again, show some code to know where u went wrong

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html and examples http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm

Comment: what are the error msgs..i now see your problem

Comment: There are no error messages, it just doesn't work the way that it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You never all the panel to the scroll pane
2. You never add the scroll pane to the applet

The basic code should be:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(...);
scrollPane.setViewportView( scrollPanel );
add( scrollPane );
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding components to a Panel so you shouldn't expect to see a scroll pane wihout showing the scrollpane. What you want to do is then add that panel to a scrollpane which would be added to ur main container.

From your code, i think your problem is

```
add(scrollPanel);
```

your should be doing this

```
add(scroll);`
```

This is because you only added the panel to the frame which does not contain any scrollpane. Since you have added the panel unto the scrollpane, you should add the scrollpane and not the panel to the main container.

Comment: by main container i mean the applet

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using Swing components (JScrollPane, JPanel, ...) in an AWT container (Applet). Try using [JApplet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html) instead.

Comment: I do not know how to port Applet to JApplet, and also, I use JPanel, JLabel, JCheckbox, and lots of other Swing components in my program, and it works fine. It's just the scroll pane that won't work.

Comment: @joseph  `I do not know how to port Applet to JApplet` just by adds `J` before `Applet`, nothing else Container will be `JApplet`

Comment: I did that, but it wouldn't run properly - I don't know why, because the compiler did not report any errors.

Comment: *"I did that, but it wouldn't run properly"*  Then there are other more fundamental problems with the code that were *revealed* by using the `JApplet`.  But stick with Swing & `JComponents` exclusively, most people have forgotten AWT components.

Comment: Look at camickr's answer. You never put your JPanel to the JScrollPane.